# gcc's const attribute with function receiving a union argument

Tags: gcc, constants, union

GCC defines a const function as:

> "functions that do not examine any values except their arguments, and have no effects except the return value. … const functions should never take pointer … arguments."

What if the function receives an argument which can be a union of either an int or a pointer to an int, does GCC check what the active member of the union is, and if it is a non pointer, does it still apply the optimization? Or is it better to never use the const attribute in this particular case?

```
typedef union A {
    int x;
    int * y;
} A;

int example(A const a) __attribute__ ((const));
```

Comment: Did you try compiling it?

Comment: The "should never take pointer arguments" is advice to the programmer, not an enforced rule.  The compiler won't stop you from defining a `const` function taking pointer arguments.  However, it will assume that a call to the function doesn't dereference the pointer.

Comment: @NateEldredge, so, based on that, a const function can compare pointers for equality and for null without ever dereferencing them and return a predictable value every single time.

Comment: @JoãoPires: Correct.

Comment: In my tests, the compiler doesn't seem to pay attention to the active member at all.  If you call the function twice with the same value of an `A` object, the second one is optimized out.  However it seems to consider "same value" in the bitwise sense.  For instance, with `sizeof(int *) > sizeof(int)`, given `a.y = &i; example(a); a.x = 5; a.y = &i; example(a);` it deletes the second call, but given `a.x = 5; example(a); a.y = &i; a.x = 5; example(a);` it does not.